# at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)

Tags: android, json

**Below is my code:**

```
public class JSON extends Activity {
    TextView json;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String twitterTimeline = getTwitterTimeline();
        try {
            String tweets = "";
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(twitterTimeline);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                int j = i+1;
                tweets +="*** " + j + " ***\n";
                tweets += "Date:" + jsonObject.getString("trends") + "\n";
                tweets += "Post:" + jsonObject.getString("name") + "\n\n";
            }
            json= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.json);
            json.setText(tweets);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String getTwitterTimeline() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/23424848.json");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                //Couldn't obtain the data
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

**I'am getting error message :**

> Invalid cookie header: "set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A136496691433468960;
>   Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 03-Apr-2015 05:28:34 UTC".
>   Unable to parse expires attribute: Fri, 03-Apr-2015 05:28:34 UTC
>   org.json.JSONException: Value
>   [{"as_of":"2013-04-03T05:28:34Z","trends":[{"events":null,"query":"%22Finding+Dory%22","url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Finding+Dory%22","promoted_content":null,"name":"Finding
>   Dory"},{"events":null,"query":"%23MentionADislike","url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23MentionADislike","promoted_content":null,"name":"#MentionADislike"},{"events":null,"query":"%23PSG","url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23PSG","promoted_content":null,"name":"#PSG"},{"events":null,"query":"%23IPLOpeningCeremony","url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23IPLOpeningCeremony","promoted_content":null,"name":"#IPLOpeningCeremony"},{"events":null,"query":"%23UCL","url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23UCL","promoted_content":null,"name":"#UCL"},{"events":null,"query":"%23GamesWePlay","url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23GamesWePlay","promoted_content":null,"name":"#GamesWePlay"},{"events":null,"query":"Juve","url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=Juve","promoted_content":null,"name":"Juve"},{"events":null,"query":"Valdes","url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=Valdes","promoted_content":null,"name":"Valdes"},{"events":null,"query":"Barca","url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=Barca","promoted_content":null,"name":"Barca"},{"events":null,"query":"Bayern","url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=Bayern","promoted_content":null,"name":"Bayern"}],"locations":[{"woeid":23424848,"name":"India"}],"created_at":"2013-04-03T05:19:03Z"}]
>   of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject at
>   org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)

can anyone please guide me where I'm doing wrong?

This JSON format how to Parse and display

```
[
{
"trends":[
{
"name":"#PappuCII",
"url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23PappuCII",
"promoted_content":null,
"query":"%23PappuCII",
"events":null
},
{
"name":"#ReplaceMovieNamesWithKamina",
"url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23ReplaceMovieNamesWithKamina",
"promoted_content":null,
"query":"%23ReplaceMovieNamesWithKamina",
"events":null
},
```

plz Help me out I'm getting confuse now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as in logcat results :

> JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

because you are getting `JSONArray` as root element in current json string instead of `JSONObject`. so you will need to first convert current string to JSONArray  then extract all JSONObject from it.chnage your code as:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray (twitterTimeline); //<convert string to JSONArray 
for (int i = 0; i < jArray .length(); i++) {
  // get all JSONObject from jArray  here..
 }
```

your current json format is:

```
[    //<<<< this is JSONArray 
  {  //<<<< this is JSONObject  inside JSONArray 


  },
 .....
]
```

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K sir can tell me in detail. actually i'm new to android.

Comment: why this Error "org.json.JSONException: No value for name"???  while Converting this url "https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/23424848.json"

Comment: @Nandu : if still getting issue then add new code and logcat results with question to get more help

Comment: the code is same sir i have follow ur code which u answered yesterday...the url which i have given above it is showing no value for name..Actually i wanted to list out the trends name..trends is an array which is containing name,url etc

Comment: @Nandu : you will need to change your code current json string structure returned for twitter instead of trying to parse using previous code for parsing any other json string

Comment: Sorry ρяσѕρєя K i'm not getting how to change structure